# Success message not displaying even after successful PHP script execution

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am having strange issue here. **contact_p.php** page sends me all error messages properly for all invalid data entered on **contact.php** form page. So I am able to print them on page in red color box and text.

**contact_p.php** page sends me success message too after successful script execution. I can check success status and message using **alert(data);** on **contact.js** page.

But for some reason it doesn't print success message in green color box and text. I mean it's doesn't print success message at all.

I am trying to solve this errors for couple of hours but no success yet. Please let me know what wrong I am doing on what page which is causing this strange issue.

**contact.php**

```
<form name="FormPRegister" id="FormPRegister" novalidate>
<div class="control-group form-group">
    .
    .
    other fields like Name, Mail, Phone, captcha etc
    .
    .
    <div id="success"></div>
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="9">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

**contact.js**

```
success: function(data) 
{
//alert(data);
var $responseText=JSON.parse(data);
if($responseText.staus == 'SUC')
{
    // Success message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " </strong>");
    $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');

    //clear all fields
    $('#FormPRegister').trigger("reset");
}

else if($responseText.status == 'ERR')
{
    // Fail message
    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
    .append("</button>");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong> " + $responseText.message + " ");
    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
}
},
```

**contact_p.php**

```
if( Invalid data then do this )
{
    $response['status']='ERR';
    $response['message']= "Invalid Secrete Code!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}

if( Valid data then do this )
{
    $response['status']='SUC';
    $response['message']= "Inquiry submitted successfully";
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its due to mistyping.
You have in your JS Code

```
if($responseText.staus == 'SUC')
```

Instead of

```
if($responseText.status == 'SUC')
```

Can you correct and retry ?
Dont you have any JS debugger like Firebug ?

EDIT : Dont forget to reload your cache before retrying : use ctrl+shift+R on Firefox for example.

Comment: I want to cry for this typo error. Such a stupid I am... spent coupe of hours and tried too many things... I am not aware about Firebug but I will definitely use it now.  But I really really appreciate your help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You mis-spell status here:

```
if($responseText.staus == 'SUC')
```

it should be :

```
if($responseText.status == 'SUC')
```